# How to Autoresize popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/sNrLQ/1/

I want the pop-over to  autoresize  based on its content.
Also I am trying to give it a max width of 400px.

My css

```
.popover2{display:block!important;width: 400px !important;}
```

And my html

```
<div class="popover popover2 left"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"><p>tellus. Donec dui tortor, commodo nec laoreet ac, </p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sNrLQ/6/)**

Try this

### css

```
.popover2{
    display:block !important;
    max-width: 400px!important;
    width:auto;
}
```

Hope this helps ,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use `min-height` max-h css property and `overflow:auto`

and usually, if youre using twitter bootstrap, the auto resizing is already taken care of, cross-browserly :)

Comment: Do you mean by height of width!!

I added 'overflow auto' and tried min height it added a scrollbar in that div

Answer (score 0):

You most configure the max-width inside boostrap.min.css. The information is resized automatically with a max width pre-set in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be usefull

```js
var $btn = $("#my_btn")
  .popover()
  .on("show.bs.popover", function(e){
    p.data("bs.popover").tip().css({"max-width": "500px"});
  });
```